# How i can Check That a user cannot enter time hours more than 8 hours in php

Tags: php

My code is taking for 8 hours from time and date field but when i give both for example i set 9 am to 4 pm then its OK. but when i insert 9am to 6am it also allow that one its almost 21 hours difference so how can i do it any one please?

```
<?php

elseif (isset($_POST['from']) && ($_POST['to']))
{
    $from_time = $_POST['from'];
    $to_time = $_POST['to'];
    $starttimestamp = strtotime($from_time);
    $endtimestamp = strtotime($to_time);
    $difference = abs($endtimestamp - $starttimestamp) / 3600;

    if ($difference > 8){
        echo "<script>alert('Oops!Your Daily Availablity Is More Than 8 Hours')</script>";
    }else{
        $query = "update donor SET from_time='" . $from_time . "',to_time='" . $to_time . "' where id=" . $_SESSION['id'];
    }
```

Comment: you trying for 9AM to 6AM, means 9AM current date to 6AM  next day ?

Comment: yeah!!! but i want that to limit for only in the range of 8 hours difference between the 1st input time and 2nd input time.

Comment: what is the input time format  ?

Comment: This is::   <input type="time" class="form-control" values="<?php $date = date("h", strtotime($row['time_d'])); echo "$date"; ?>" id="until_t" name="from"/>

Answer (score 0):

Take the input in 24 hrs format including DataTime. Then change your code as below.

I hope this code will solve your problem.

```
<?php
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kathmandu'); 

        $datetime1 = new DateTime('2010-10-11 24:00:00'); // change date & time
        $datetime2 = new DateTime('2010-11-11 24:00:00');  //change date & time
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        echo $interval->format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')."<br />";

        $year =  $interval->format('%Y') * 365 * 24;
        $month = $interval->format('%m') * 30 * 24 ;
        $day = $interval->format('%d') * 24 ;
        $hour = $interval->format('%H');
        $minute = $interval->format('%i')/ 60;
        $seconds = $interval->format('%s')/(60*60);

        $time_diff = $year + $month + $day + $hour + $minute + $seconds;

        echo $time_diff;

        if ($time_diff > 8) {
            echo 'More then 8 hour';
        }else{
            echo 'ok';
        }
?>
```

Comment: @TarangP See the answer. I have Changed it.

Comment: Thanx for u comment but bro still its allowing the same when i put 9am and 6am it storres it

Comment: @user3712207 9am to 6am it's difference is only about 3 hours. if you are saying the next day 6am than you should try changing your date to. Also you can try using 24 hrs format rather than using 12:00 AM & 12:00PM

Comment: but here is 6AM is my 2nd time which means for me that its rounding towards next day and i dont want that to store it in database..

Comment: @user3712207 I have edited my above answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify full date time in request.

```
  <?php
      $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($row['time_d']))
  ?>

  <input type="time" class="form-control" values="<?= $date ?>" id="until_t" name="from"/>
```

Then you will got correct difference between both start and end time.

Comment: still not sir!!
its very challenging i did my task almost 80% but this condition put me in tough !!